# How does the CPython Interpreter handle OOP

Tags: python, c, oop, cpython

A friend recently asked "How does the CPython Interpreter actually handle OOP (Object Orientated Programming)?".

This question ended up making me confused, as I understand C isn't an Object Orientated language.

I tried [Googling it](https://www.google.com/#q=CPython+Object+Oriented+Programming), searching [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CPython%20interpret%20OOP) and even reading the [CPython Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython). But I couldn't find anything useful.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def getInfo(self):
        return "Name: " + self.name + "\nAge: " + str(self.age)

# How the heck does CPython handle this?
personOne = Person("Bob", 34)
personTwo = Person("Rob", 26)

print( personOne.getInfo() )
print( personTwo.getInfo() )
```

So now I really wanna know! Just how does the CPython Interpreter handle things like Objects if itself isn't Object Orientated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full complexity of Python's OOP implementation is far beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer, but it's possible to provide an overview. This will gloss over a lot of details, like metaclasses, multiple inheritance, descriptors, and the C-level API. Still, it should give you a sense of why implementing such a thing is possible, as well as a general impression of how it's done. If you want the full details, you should browse the [CPython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython).

---

An object like an instance of your `Person` class consists of the following things:

- A class
- A dict holding its attributes
- Other stuff that's not relevant right now, like `__weakref__`.

A class is also pretty simple. It has

- A base class
- A dict holding its attributes
- Other stuff that's not relevant right now, like the class name.

---

When you define a class with a `class` statement, Python bundles up a pointer to the base class you picked (or `object` if you didn't pick one) and a dict holding the methods you defined, and that's your new class object. It's kind of like the following tuple

```
Person = (object,
          {'__init__': <that __init__ method you wrote>,
           'getInfo': <that getInfo method you wrote>},
          those irrelevant bits we're glossing over)
```

but not a tuple. (At C level, this record is almost, but not quite, implemented as a struct.)

---

When you create an instance of your class, Python bundles together a pointer to your class and a new dict for the instance's attributes, and that's your instance. It's kind of like the following tuple:

```
personOne = (Person, {}, those irrelevant bits we're glossing over)
```

but again, not a tuple. Again, it's almost, but not quite, implemented as a struct at C level.

Then it runs `__init__`, passing `__init__` the new instance and whatever other arguments you provided to your class:

```
Person.__init__(personOne, "Bob", 34)
```

Attribute assignment is translated to setting entries in the object's dict, so the assignments in `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
```

cause the dict to end up in the following state:

```
{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 34}
```

---

When you call `personOne.getInfo()`, Python looks in `personOne`'s dict, then its class's dict, then its superclass's dict, etc., until it finds an entry for the `'getInfo'` key. The associated value will be the `getInfo` method. If the method was found in a class dict, Python will insert `personOne` as the first argument. (The details of how it knows to insert that argument are in the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a small thought-experiment: Your CPU is not "object oriented" at all. Instead, it's only able to execute instructions like "add register 1 to register 2 and put the result in register 3" and "if register 5 is greater than zero, then execute this goto statement." And yet somehow the CPU can run Python and other object-oriented languages. How?